# Order list with weighting for exact match then lose match in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking at how to weight results to prefer exact matches. For example, if I have `monkey` and `monkey business` and I search `monkey` it should return the record with **monkey** before **monkey business**. However for a reason unknown to me it returns **monkey business** first and scores it more.

I have tried several iterations including match_phrase, match, term (all within bool).

My latest query is (I have tidied it up as there was a lot of commented code so excuse me if the syntax is broken):

```
 "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must" : [ // All of these clauses must match. The equivalent of AND
              {
                "match": {
                  "supplier": {
                    "query": search ? search : "",
                    "minimum_should_match": "30%"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": [ // At least one of these clauses must match. The equivalent of OR
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                   "supplier": {
                      "query": search ? search : "",
                      "slop":  50
                   }
                }
              },             
            ],
            'filter' : [ // Clauses that must match, but are run in non-scoring, filtering mode
            { "match": { "signup": 100 }},
            { "match": { "isApproved": true }}
            ]
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have all the matching documents retrieved, and have an high score for those fully matching. Therefore combine in a `bool` query a "simple" match in the `must`-part and a match with 100% `minimum_should_match` in the `should`-part:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
       "must": [
         {
           "match":{
             "supplier": "monkey business"
           }
         }
       ],
       "should": [
         {
           "match":{
             "supplier": {
                "query": "monkey business",
                "minimum_should_match": "100%" 
             }
           }
         }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```